# My Java Program only Loops Once

Tags: java, android, debugging

I have been working on this program for about a day now and I can not figure out why it is not working All I can find out is that the section of the program that checks if the code has been used yet does not work perfectly.

The goal of the program is to pick random numbers until it matches the code you entered. It simulates the Pattern Lock on Android Phones, so for me to make it more efficient I added a Array List to keep track of all the  guesses it makes in order for it to not repeat itself.

My Code

```
import java.util.*;
public class CrackerMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Instances
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random gen=new Random();
    //Variables
    long endTime=0;
    long startTime=0;
    boolean solved=false;
    boolean newnumb=false;
    int ran=0;
    int correct=0;
    boolean running=true;
    int dots;
    int codex;
    int codey;
    int zero;
    int x;
    int y;
    ArrayList<int[][]>  UsedCodes = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
    int[][] code={{0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0}};
    int[][] guess={{0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0},
                   {0,0,0}};
    UsedCodes.add(guess);
    //Program

    //Enter Code
    System.out.println("Enter a Code to Crack: ");
    System.out.println("1 for 1st etc. 0 for Not Used");
    System.out.println("y x0  1  2");
    System.out.println("0 {x}{x}{x}");
    System.out.println("1 {x}{x}{x}");
    System.out.println("2 {x}{x}{x}");
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 0,0");
    code[0][0]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 0,1");
    code[0][1]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 0,2");
    code[0][2]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 1,0");
    code[1][0]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 1,1");
    code[1][1]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 1,2");
    code[1][2]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 2,0");
    code[2][0]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 2,1");
    code[2][1]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Number for 2,2");
    code[2][2]=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Entered");
    System.out.println("{"+code[0][0]+"}{"+code[0][1]+"}{"+code[0][2]+"}");
    System.out.println("{"+code[1][0]+"}{"+code[1][1]+"}{"+code[1][2]+"}");
    System.out.println("{"+code[2][0]+"}{"+code[2][1]+"}{"+code[2][2]+"}");
    //guessing
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(solved==false){
        correct=0;
        newnumb=false;
        while(newnumb==false){
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=1;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=2;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=3;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=4;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=5;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=6;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=7;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=8;
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=9;
            //Enter Zeros Randomly
            zero=gen.nextInt(100);
            if(zero==0){
                x=gen.nextInt(3);
                y=gen.nextInt(3);
                guess[x][y]=0;  
            }
            zero=gen.nextInt(100);
            if(zero==0){
                x=gen.nextInt(3);
                y=gen.nextInt(3);
                guess[x][y]=0;  
            }
        zero=gen.nextInt(100);
        if(zero==0){
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=0;  
        }
        zero=gen.nextInt(100);
        if(zero==0){
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=0;  
        }
        zero=gen.nextInt(100);
        if(zero==0){
            x=gen.nextInt(3);
            y=gen.nextInt(3);
            guess[x][y]=0;  
        }

        //Check if New
        for(int i=0; i>ran; i++){
            if(guess!=UsedCodes.get(i)){
                correct++;
            }
        }

        if(correct==ran){
            newnumb=true;
            ran++;  
        }
    }
    //Add Guess to ArrayList
    UsedCodes.add(guess);
    //Say What Guessed
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("{"+guess[0][0]+"}{"+guess[0][1]+"}{"+guess[0][2]+"}");
    System.out.println("{"+guess[1][0]+"}{"+guess[1][1]+"}{"+guess[1][2]+"}");
    System.out.println("{"+guess[2][0]+"}{"+guess[2][1]+"}{"+guess[2][2]+"}");

    //Check if Worked
    if(code[0][0]==guess[0][0]&&code[0][1]==guess[0][1]&&code[0][2]==guess[0][2]&&code[1][0]==guess[1][0]&&code[1][1]==guess[1][1]&&code[1][2]==guess[1][2]&&code[2][0]==guess[2][0]&&code[2][1]==guess[2][1]&&code[2][2]==guess[2][2]){
        solved=true;
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        ran++;
    }
    else{
        guess[0][0]=0;
        guess[0][1]=0;
        guess[0][2]=0;
        guess[1][0]=0;
        guess[1][1]=0;
        guess[1][2]=0;
        guess[2][0]=0;
        guess[2][1]=0;
        guess[2][2]=0;
    }

}   
System.out.println("Solution");
System.out.println("{"+guess[0][0]+"}{"+guess[0][1]+"}{"+guess[0][2]+"}");
System.out.println("{"+guess[1][0]+"}{"+guess[1][1]+"}{"+guess[1][2]+"}");
System.out.println("{"+guess[2][0]+"}{"+guess[2][1]+"}{"+guess[2][2]+"}");
System.out.println("Broke Your Passcode in: "+((endTime - startTime)/1000000000) + " seconds");
```

}
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why randomly? **It could never find the secret pattern**. What you want to do is to **try all possible combinations** (brute-force approach).

There are two cases:

- If the pattern has a fixed known length, say 4, you can just hardcode some nested for-loops, in our example 4.
- Otherwise you need a recursive approach: you pick one cell, you remove it from the "pickable" cells, you stash it somewhere, and you repeat the process. When there is nothing left to pick or you picked the number of cells you wanted, you test whether this is your secret pattern and in that case you return it.

In the (hastily written) code below, I model the screen lock board with a list of numbers, from 1 to 9 (no need of matrices). The secret pattern is also a list with only some cells selected, order matters. The method `print()` prints the board and puts a `.`, if the cell is not in the secret pattern, otherwise it outputs the position of the cell in the secret pattern.

For example, I pick the secret 4 5 1 9, in this order. The output will be:

```
3..
12.
..4
```

because the board is represented as

```
123
456
789
```

Here comes the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Cracker {
    static List<Integer> secret = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
        add(4); add(5); add(1); add(9);
    }};

    static final int MIN_DIGITS = 1;
    static final int MAX_DIGITS = 9;

    static List<Integer> crack(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> choosen, 
            int depth) {
        if (left.isEmpty() || depth == 0) {
            return choosen.equals(secret) ? choosen : null;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < left.size(); i++) {
            int choice = left.get(i);
            left.remove(i);
            choosen.add(choice);
            List<Integer> res = crack(left, choosen, depth - 1);
            left.add(i, choice);
            if (res != null) return res;
            choosen.remove(choosen.size() - 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static List<Integer> crack() {
        for (int i = MIN_DIGITS; i <= MAX_DIGITS; i++) {
            List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
                add(1); add(2); add(3);
                add(4); add(5); add(6);
                add(7); add(8); add(9);
            }};
            List<Integer> choosen = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            List<Integer> res = crack(left, choosen, i);
            if (res != null) return res;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void print(List<Integer> board) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(board.contains(i) ? board.indexOf(i) + 1 : ".");
            if (i % 3 == 0) System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(secret);
        System.out.println();
        print(crack()); // should be the same!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I do not completely understand your code (especially since I only know basic Java). But where does it check to see if it is the correct code.

Comment: In this line `return choosen.equals(secret) ? choosen : null;`. Of course, you could substitute this with a method `test()` that does not have any knowledge of the `secret` and/or enter the secret from the console as in your example.

Comment: The idea is the following: the public method `crack()` tests all the patterns with length 1, length 2, ... length 9. The method `crack(List, List, int depth)` tests all the patterns of a fixed depth, say 4. It loops over all possible combinations with length 4, picking one digit at a time. When it picked 4 digits, the depth will be 0, so you run a test: `choosen.equals(secret)`. If they are are the same, you're done, otherwise you keep looping. Recursive code is not super easy, so take you time to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> My Java Program only Loops Once

This is because in the second iteration of the guessing loop `while(solved==false){` the inner loop `while(newnumb==false){` is an endless loop, because:

- minor typo - instead of

  ```
          for(int i=0; i>ran; i++){
  ```

  you meant

  ```
          for (int i=0; i<ran; i++)…
  ```
- major error - the variable `guess` is just a *reference* to an array, and so the statement

  ```
      //Add Guess to ArrayList
      UsedCodes.add(guess);
  ```

  does not add a copy of the guess to the `UsedCodes`, but only a copy of the reference, and thus subsequent changes to the original `guess` manifestly alter the values referred to by `UsedCodes` and what's more, in

  ```
          //Check if New
          for(int i=0; i…
              if(guess!=UsedCodes.get(i)){
  ```

  the comparison always yields `false`, since `guess` and `UsedCodes.get(i)` are the same reference. To rectify these issues, allocate a `new` guess at the start of each cycle of the loop

  ```
      while (solved==false)
      {
          guess = new int[3][3];
  ```

  and compare the array values:

  ```
          // Check if new
          for (int i=0; i<ran; i++)
          {
              if (!Arrays.deepEquals(guess, UsedCodes.get(i)))…
  ```